# Convert a nested structure to flat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm

I have a nested structure as below:

```
       arr[3].title="a3";        
       arr[3].nextArr=[];
       arr[2].title="a2"; 
       arr[2].nextArr=arr[3];
       arr[1].title="a1"; 
       arr[1].nextArr=arr[2];
       arr[0].title="a0"; 
       arr[0].nextArr=arr[1];
```

like here!:

```
|_
  |_
    |_
```

As you see, I have one array called arr with four members.

How can I make four separated arrays from arr?

```
arrayOne=[{title:"a1"},{nextArr:[]}];    
arraytwo=[{title:"a2"},{nextArr:[]}];
.
.
.
```

Update: I need this converts in my AngularJS controller.js. I get a response from server which contains an array as above. And I have to make it flat. The count of inner arrays are not constant. I didn't mention that because I didn't know the algorithm. But, according to answers, it seems Itt was better if I explained it more.

```
Result = {arr[title:"a0",nextArr:{title:"a1",nextArr:{title:"a2",nextArr:{......}}}]};
```

Comment: `arrayOne=arr[1];
arraytwo=arr[2];`

Comment: It looks like a `"a0" -> "a1" -> "a2" -> []` single linked list. But what is the type of `nextArray` field? How can it point both to `[]` and to structure of two fields `title, nextArray`? If it's a list, list traversing algorithms would work.

Comment: All of arrays have similar type.in last one, the next array is an empty array. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yield` to create an enumerator that recursively walks the hierarchy:

```
public IEnumerable<{class}> Flatten({class}[] data)
{
    foreach({class} parent in data)
    {
        yield return parent;

        foreach({class} child in flatten(parent.nextArr))
            yield return child;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to loop over the objects in the `data` array for this to work.

Comment: @juharr Thanks, fixed.

Comment: Does this answer the question? Once you have this method, can you show how to get the result that the OP says he wants?